# How do I manipulate Getters in computed property before using it in the html template?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am mapping getters from my Vuex store as a computed property and want to manipulate the property (its an array of objects) before using it in the component template. Any idea how I can do that?

I have tried watching the computed property but that doesn't work.

```
import {mapGetters} from 'vuex
computed: {
  ...mapGetters([
   'property'
    ])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use your getter in another custom property like you will do for a simple variable :

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="item in transformedItems" :key="item">{{item}}</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(['items']),
    transformedItems() {
      return this.items.map(item => item.name)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

And then you can use `transformedItems` in your template

Comment: ahh, I can't believe I didn't think of that. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Sometimes you just need to deliver a project based on old code of a colleague with a framework you have never worked before. Then Q&As like this are a life saver. @HamidMian You can still accept the answer.